# Django in real service, Do I have to set these if else statements to prevent abuse?

Tags: python, django

EXAMPLE1:

```
def example(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.is_ajax():
            #do something
```

EXAMPLE2:

```
def example(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        if request.is_ajax():
            #do something
        else:
            #do something
    else:
        #do something
```

If django project has that above `EXAMPLE1` code, even it doesn't have any `else:` statement like `EXAMPLE2`, is it okay to run real service?

I wonder absense of `else:` statement will be chance of being abused or some bad things.

In real service, Do I have to consider statement almost case of request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is *subjective*. But the rule of thumb is that, you don't want to expose any URL endpoint on any method that you are not willing to serve -- it's better to return a 405 (Method not allowed) (or 404 -- to some extent) instead. Check out the [list of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

I would definitely implement your second example, if i were you.

Just to note, if you were to return a 404 in any endpoint, you can easily [customize logging of 404 entries using django's error reporting system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/error-reporting/#errors).

Comment: Thank you for answer, But even there is 405 http status, why would you use second example? Is there any other good reason than you can customize request method and response?

Comment: @touchingtwist just to be explicit about the error. This goes a long way in usability for users and also readability of your code for you.

Comment: @touchingtwist Glad I could help :)